# Webpack 2 - multiple output files with the same content

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to build 2 output files with the same content.
One tagged with the version number (taken from package.json)
and second tagged with "latest".

My (simplified) configuration looks like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var version = require('./package.json').version;

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    js: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist/sdk'),
    filename: [`oc-sdk-${version}.js`, 'oc-sdk-latest.js']
  }
}
```

But this isn't currently supported by webpack. I'm getting this error:
`configuration.output.filename should be a string`

Is there a way to do this? Using a plugin or something?

Thanks for any advice or suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would fall outside Webpack's duties.

Instead I'd suggest you to add a couple of lines to your build setup to copy/rename your files.

[`on-build-webpack`](https://github.com/kossnocorp/on-build-webpack) plugin, for example, provides you a callback which is fired after the build task is completed.